# Suppress Compiler "null check" Warning Conditionally

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nullable-reference-types

I have a centralized method for checking results from a repository. This includes a check if the `Entity`property is null.

Sadly this has the annoying side-effect of showing a compiler warning, since there is no null check in the method that contains the call.

This is probably a long shot, but is there a way to tell the compiler to treat my method like a manual null check? I would prefer not to disable the warning globally, since it is actually pretty useful. Are there any other workarounds for this?

```
public Group GetGroup(Group.GroupId groupId)
{
    if (groupId.Value == null || groupId.Is(0))
        throw new Exception("Can not get group with ID: null/0");

    EntityInteractionResult<Group> readResult = _groupRepository.ReadById((ulong)groupId.Value);

    readResult.ValidateSuccessAndEntity(); // <- This checks if Entity is null
    return readResult.Entity; // <- CS8603 possible null reference return
}
```

Comment: Does `return readResult!.Entity;` do what you want?

Comment: @rshepp Kind of. It would be `readResult.Entity!`, since Entity is the nullable type. But this has the downside of possibly causing errors if the `ValidateSuccessAndEntity` is ever removed. Though I assume this might be the best I can get.

Comment: Try: `public Group?`

Comment: What happens if `ValidateSuccessAndEntity` finds a null? If it throws on null, could you make it return the non-null type (e.g., type signature using generics similar to `T ValidateSuccessAndEntity<T>(EntityInterationResult<T?> value)`) -- *apologies, I reposted this comment as my original had a typo and the edit timer ran out*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ValidateSuccessAndEntity` is method of `EntityInteractionResult` then you can use `MemberNotNullAttribute` to list members which won't be null when the method returns:

```cs
public class Result
{
    public string? Value { get; set; } 

    public Result()
    {
    }

    [MemberNotNull(nameof(Value))]
    public void Validate()
    {
        if(Value is null)
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

```cs
var result = new Result();
result.Validate();
var c = result.Value[1]; // "warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference" if previous line commented out
```

[Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACh8AGAAn2IDoARASwEMBzAOwgGcAXFmF4MAwhAwwAglzYAbAJ68WvANwV8AZjqEaomgG8KNE3W34UNALIAKAJSHjp5wDc2UGrF4BXOfxoAvDRcMADuNABKMD5+9urkzs5evvwMAGryLBhs/DBxTok0bh5ggZ7RKeny3jAA2sQAuqo0APQtwRA0oe5cLFwcBYmDru7lMfzEZSHhUeP5CYVFo2CTQcl+jBlyNfVNre3dUL39gwC+FOfkGua6sykURgsmWnTEVAD8NFs1hjQcMPxmrwAc1TjQKIMXndYnZBo9nJdBrUrDAALbAGBQAByEH4WN8chsslRMAgADMbN8YHY7A1IeZLFssjk8rCno52c4WBSqTQVMECWzFol+AALKAQcLTGgAUQQYBgAAdBBAuPMERcgA===)

Read more:

- [Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#helper-methods-membernotnull-and-membernotnullwhen)